# Share one back office (database) over three drupal websites

Tags: database

I'm wondering if there is a way to have one back office for three drupal websites with different domaine names, so I can share users over the three websites, I think I'm gonna have one database for all my drupal websites, but I'm not sure how I can achieve this using drupal.

Comment: You need to use domain module for the above case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teeyo,

You can do this with the domains module that can be found here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/domain

The installation instructions can be found here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/477372

Don't forget to edit your settings.php file ;-)

I used the module myself a couple of times, so if you need any assistance, just let me know :-)

Comment: Thank you @guardian, yup it's great module, I started using it, now I'm exploring it, (trying to add the domain blocks module so I can control the display of my modules) ... I'll contact you when if I need anything ;)